# Texture paint brush looks odd

Tags: modeling, texture-painting

I have been having trouble with the texture paint tool, whenever I draw it looks grainy and weird. I have looked at the texture properties tab and it didn't look like I had made a texture brush on accident.

[image: What the brush looks like when I draw]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: maybe you've opened a texture in the N panel > Tools > Brush Settings > Texture? In that case, close it

Comment: @moonboots, Nope, nothing there.

Comment: maybe pack your images and share? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sorry, but how do I share the file?

Comment: you need to upload your file on pasteall.org/blend, it will change the URL address, copy paste the URL

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/e3a7142ddf114686b52ee0ff9566eeb9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 meshes overlapping within the same object, in *Edit* mode you can press <kbd>L</kbd> to select one, then delete, the painting will work normally.